# Return list of values from getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, getjson

I need to check a json file and see if I have a match on my page.  Said json file is huge contains a ton of different values and objects.  Looks something like this:

```
name: john doe,
id: 5891,
description: product,

name: jane doe,
id: 5892,
description: product,
```

etc

I only care about the "id" object and it's values, and don't want to skim the entire file for my need.

Is there a way I can do a getJson with jquery:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.mysite.com&callback=searchCallback', function(data) {

});
```

and return only the values in "id", and then check if there's a match?  Just looking for a 'yes its there' or 'no its not'...

Comment: You can't get partials with ajax, and you can't check if somethings there without getting all of it. Why not create a serverside script that does just what you want, and call that script with ajax instead.

Comment: either your sever needs to do it,  or you need to loop over it.

Comment: You should handle it on server side.

Comment: No access to fire a server side script :)  Limited with a front end CMS so it would have to be client side...

Comment: That means you have to download the huge file completely and filter it on the client side, period.

Comment: NB: you comment in your code: *"//data is the JSON string"*: this is not true: jQuery provides you with the decoded object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you cannot manipulate server response. That will be hacker's paradise. Server should do that.

---

This is what you can do.

Use [Array.prototype.any()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/any)

```
var needle = 707; //desired id
var result = $.getJSON('https://api.mysite.com&callback=searchCallback', function(data) {
    var found = data.any(function(element, index, array){
        return element.id === needle;
    });
});
```